# FeinCMS; how to make sure that content_type's process(), registered with Base extending class, gets executed

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I have a custom model Foo which extends feincms.models.Base so I can register content_types to it.

```
Foo.create_content_type(content.SomeContentType)
```

Now I want to make sure the `process()` function explained [here](http://www.feinheit.ch/media/labs/feincms/contenttypes.html#influencing-request-processing-through-a-content-type) gets executed.

With feincms.module.Page this is no problem. But on a Base extending model this is not the case. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, you'll have to call those methods yourself.
Elephantblog contains an example of how to achieve this:

https://github.com/feincms/feincms-elephantblog/blob/master/elephantblog/views.py#L78

Yes, that's a lot of copy-pasted code. There is an open issue on
github which tracks problems like this. Solving #241 in a general way
would mean that much more code around the content types could be
reused.

https://github.com/feincms/feincms/issues/241